# Menu Button Won't Work?

Tags: java, swing, awt, mouselistener

I have a menu button that is supposed to transition into the game state once you click on it, but it won't work. Here is my MouseInput class. Ignore all of the methods except for the MousePressed method.

```
package com.game.src.main;

import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

public class MouseInput implements MouseListener
{   
    @Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
{
    int mx = e.getX();
    int my = e.getY();

    /**
    public Rectangle playButton = new Rectangle(Game.WIDTH/2 + 120, 150, 100, 50);
    public Rectangle helpButton = new Rectangle(Game.WIDTH/2 + 120, 250, 100, 50);
    public Rectangle quitButton = new Rectangle(Game.WIDTH/2 + 120, 350, 100, 50);
    */

    if (mx >= Game.WIDTH/2 + 120 && mx <= Game.WIDTH/2 + 220)
    {
        if (my >= 150 && mx <= 200)
            Game.State = Game.STATE.GAME;
    }

}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Here is the init method, which is part of the Game class. I bolded and italicized the line of code where I supposedly use the addMouseListener method to enable the mouse functionality (but clearly it doesn't work).

```
public static enum STATE
{
    MENU, 
    GAME
};

public static STATE State = STATE.MENU;

public void init()
{
    requestFocus();
    BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
    try
    {
        spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/spritesheettemplate.png");
        background = loader.loadImage("/bkg.png");
    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    addKeyListener(new KeyInput(this));
    ***addMouseListener(new MouseInput());***

    tex = new Textures(this);

    p = new Player(WIDTH/2*SCALE - 16, HEIGHT/2*SCALE - 16, tex);
    c = new Controller(this, tex);

    menu = new Menu();

    eA = c.getEntityA();
    eB = c.getEntityB();

    c.addEnemy(enemyCount);
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. This is the final step in my game. I'm following a tutorial series on Youtube, but the uploader never responds to questions, so you guys are my only hope (I guess I'm being a little dramatic). If you need me to post more parts of my code, I can do that.

Comment: When you find that half of your `MouseListener` methods are empty, switch to a `MouseAdapter`

Comment: _"I have a menu button"_.. Why not use an `ActionListener`?

Answer (score 2):

Just add an ActionListener to that menu button without dealing with MouseListener.

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                Game.State = Game.STATE.GAME;
            }
        });
```